# Pandas rolling sum of prior n elements with NaN values

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I have a pandas Series named `df` which look like :

```
NaN
2
3
NaN
NaN
4
6
4
8
```

I would like to calculate the rolling sum only if there are 5 prior elements. If there is less than 5 prior elements the output should be NaN [see image below].
When there are five prior elements with some NaN element, then NaN should be treated like zeros.

I tried

```
df.rolling(window=5).sum()
```

But I get only NaN which is not what I look for.

I also used min_periods=1 as well (suggested in many stackoverflow posts) but it does not work.

Below I show the input, expected output, and I explain why the expected output should be as such.

[image]

Comment: Are your `Nan` null or the string `'Nan'`?

Comment: @QuangHoang they are null [not strings]

Comment: You can try: `df.fillna(0).rolling(5).sum()`.